# IPad OpenGL Es Application flickering

Tags: iphone, ipad, opengl-es, rendering

I have an opengl es application on my ipad which is basically a paint application, uses pretty much the same code as glpaint, the sample from apple.

When I run it in the simulator, everything looks fine, the lines render properly etc.
But when I put it onto the actual ipad, every time I touch the screen, the entire screen flickers as its updating, and the lines that i draw with my finger are dashed with holes in them unless I draw extremely slowly.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have this problem too…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set the `kEAGLDrawablePropertyRetainedBacking` option to `YES` in `CAEAGLLayer`'s `drawableProperties` property when initializing the GL view.

Reference: [Apple Technical Q&A](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2010/qa1650.html).